# JavaScript getTimezoneOffset() for January 1, 1970

Tags: javascript

I have the next case:

```
new Date().timezoneOffset() //returns -180. That's ok.
```

but

```
new Date(0).timezoneOffset() //returns -120.
```

Please help me to understand why new Date(0).timezoneOffset() returns -120 instead of -180.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the effect of Daylight Savings or "Summer" time.

If it were December right now, you would not have asked the question :)