# Date.getHours Date.toLocalString returns different time

Tags: javascript, date

I have the code:

```js
var d1 = new Date('1970-01-01');
d1.toLocaleString();             // (1) returns 1/1/1970, 3:00:00 AM
d1.getHours();                   // (2) returns 2

var d2 = new Date('2017-01-01');
d2.toLocaleString();             // (3) returns 1/1/2017, 2:00:00 AM 
d2.getHours();                   // (4) returns 2
```

Why the (1) and (3) returns different time, but (2) and (4) the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @palash—how is [*JavaScript getTimezoneOffset() for January 1, 1970*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336167/javascript-gettimezoneoffset-for-january-1-1970) a duplicate? Why does *toLocaleString* give a different hour for the OP than *getHours*? They should both be local time in the same timezone, whatever that is.

Comment: moreover Firefox returns the same hours with _toLocalString()_ and _getHours()_, but Chrome and Safari not.

Comment: Find out that this is a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=731141#c3

Comment: I've found a similar bug in Safari around midnight on the daylight saving changeover date.